# Explain this mapping notation, sigma mapping from R to the power of a set (I) mapping to M.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

I am going through my university lecture notes for Abstract algebra, and I am on a chapter about (Free and finitely genereated modules) it goes like so,

Let m be an R-module and I a set. Define canonical map

$\sigma: R^{(I)}= \bigoplus_{i \in I}R \rightarrow M $,

(r$_i$)$ \mapsto $  $\sum_{i \in I}r_{i}x_{i}$,

extending homothety $h_{x_{i}}:R \rightarrow M$ to a sum.

I know sigma is a mapping from R to the set I to M, I get this part,
but what does R to the power of the set I mean, $R^{(I)}$? does it have anything to do with the power set? It is confusing me because it is equal to the direct some of elements of i in I.

Also where does $x_{i}$ come from in the second mapping?

Ok basically I don't understand what the mapping means, so can you please explain it in a very simplton meaner.

Comment: What you've written says what $R^{(I)}$ is. It's the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I}{R}$, i.e. a free $R$-module on $|I|$-many generators

Answer (score 0):

The general notion that $R^{(I)}$ is an instance of is the notion of a [copower](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower) which is often written (in general contexts) as $I\otimes R$ where you need to recognize that $I$ is a different "kind" of object than $R$ otherwise this notation is ambiguous.  Any category with all coproducts has a copower with respect to sets and that is what is happening here.

In an [Abelian (or more generally additive) category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/additive+and+abelian+categories) like $R\mathbf{Mod}$, you have [biproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct) which is simply the fact that finite coproducts and finite products coincide.  So, for finite $I$, $R^{(I)} = \coprod_{i\in I}R \cong \prod_{i\in I}R \cong R^I$ where $R^I$ is the [power](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power) and the notation is referring to a common notation for the set of functions from $I$ to $R$. For infinite $I$, though, the previous argument doesn't hold but $R^{(I)}$ is still similar to $R^I$.  In particular, $R^{(I)}$ is the subset of $R^I$ such that any function in it is $0$ for all but finitely many indices.

The universal property of $\bigoplus_{i\in I}R$ is: given any $R$-module $M$ and $I$-indexed collection of morphisms $x_i : R \to M$, there exists a unique morphism $\sigma : \bigoplus_{i\in I}R \to M$ such that $\sigma \circ \iota_i = x_i$ where $\iota_i : R \to \bigoplus_{i\in I}R$ is the $i$th injection. $\sigma$ is just the sum that you specify which will be well-defined since all but finitely many $r_i$ will be $0$.  When you say that $\sigma$ is a mapping from $R$ to $I \to M$, you are actually using the adjunction $$R\mathbf{Mod}(N^{(I)},M)\cong \prod_{i\in I}R\mathbf{Mod}(N,M)\cong R\mathbf{Mod}(N,M^I)$$ which holds in any category with $I$-indexed powers and copowers. This is just the fact that an $I$-indexed collection of morphisms $x_i : R \to M$ is just as much an $I$-indexed collection of morphisms into $M$ as it is an $I$-indexed collection of morphisms out of $R$.